# Usage of glBindBufferRange with transform feedback

Tags: opengl, geometry-shader, transform-feedback

I have a buffer that I would like to fill over successive transform feedbacks, and I am wondering how exactly to do this.

`glBindBufferRange` has five arguments, I understand that the first three are equivalent to the arguments of `glBindBufferBase`, but I have a few questions about the `offset` and `size` arguments.

If my first transform feedback produced `n` primitives, as retrieved from `GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_PRIMITIVES_WRITTEN`, my primitives are points, and I want to continue from that position in the buffer, should the offset of `glBindBufferRange` be set to `n*4*sizeof(GLfloat)`? (assuming I am retrieving a vec4 geometry shader output)

The docs just say that `offset` and `size` should be in basic machine units (although they have two different types, GLintptr and GLsizeiptr), but I'm not exactly sure what that means, so I assumed bytes, is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the amount of data written to a buffer during transform feedback is the number of primitives written * the number of components of those primitives * the size of a primitive. And yes, "basic machine units" is standardese for "byte".

Comment: Yes sorry, it is a bit unclear. These are completely separate transform feedbacks. I really want to know how to calculate where to start writing into the buffer of the second feedback, ie the offset to use so I don't leave a gap in the buffer or overwrite what I have already written.

Comment: @leohutson: See my last sentence.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, I think I understand it pretty well now. If you don't mind, I would like to ask a slightly tangential question. In my current code, after my initial transform feedback, I have a while loop that acts as a barrier and just "pauses" the program until the GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_PRIMITIVES_WRITTEN query is available. If I was to get rid of this and just calculate the expected number of primitives myself, would it be safe to bind the re-bind the buffer and do the second feedback immediately afterwards, or are there concurrency issues?